# Javafx metadata

Tags: java, javafx, metadata, media

I've tried to find out how to get metadata from a media for some time but nothing works so far. I have class Song where I have SimpleStringProperties like title, artist etc. I try to set values for them in class constructor:

```
private final SimpleStringProperty title;
private final SimpleStringProperty artist;

public Song(String path) {
    this.song = new MediaPlayer(new Media(path));
    this.artist = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "artist");
    this.title = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "title");
    this.song.setOnReady(() -> {
        title.set(song.getMedia().getMetadata().get("title").toString());
        artist.set(song.getMedia().getMetadata().get("artist").toString());
    });
}
```

Then I try to make a new song in a fxml controller:

```
Song song = new Song(path);
System.out.println(song.getTitle());
System.out.println(song.getArtist());
```

and I see in the console

```
null
null
```

I know that in the `setOnReady()` method it shows title and artist properly. I've had a solution with `Platform.runLater()` but it doesn't work fine when there is more new songs. I've read something about `synchronized()` but I have no idea how to use it. I am waiting for some solutions. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `getTitle()` and `getArtist()` before the handler gets invoked (i.e. before the `MediaPlayer` is ready).

Presumably, you don't really want to display these to the system console and are just doing that for testing. Try something like

```
Label titleLabel = new Label();
Label artistLabel = new Label();
Song song = new Song(path);
titleLabel.textProperty().bind(song.titleProperty());
artistLabel.textProperty().bind(song.artistProperty());
```

and then display those labels in your UI. They will update automatically when the data are available.

Comment: I have one more question. I want to check if song is already in playlist while adding a new song. I have a `SimpleListProperty<Song> playlist` and I use `contains()` method. I've overridden `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods in Song class but when it comes to comparing songs fields like title, artist etc. they seem not to be initialized yet. It causes that `contains()` method doesn't return what it should. Is there any way to wait until all of the fields are initialized?